# Can I replace a placeholder inside a php tag?

Tags: php

Here is my code my .php page, which is a template to create other profile pages.

```
    <?php
    $dj = Helper::getUserProfileInfo('dj','{thedjid}');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>{username} Home page</title> 
</head>

<body> 
Hello,<br /> 
<img href="<?php echo $dj->getAvatar(); ?>"/><br/>
this is my new home page. Here is my data:<br /><br />
<?php echo 'Dj name: '. $dj->getName();?>
<br /> 
<?php echo 'Contact for booking: '. $dj->getEmail();?> <br /> 

</body>
</html>
```

And when I create any new page, I want to replace this - {thedjid}(which is at the top of the page) to an id number.
Yes I am trying to create a new php page for each user because of SEO. So that if people search on google, the user can come out. 
Just like twitter, everyone has a page.

I just felt it was possible to replace a word in the php section of the template, so that the user information can be pulled out whenever the page is visited.
Please is this possible?

Comment: How about using a *variable*?

Comment: An id number of what, from where? Can you edit your question to provide more clarity?

Comment: Do you mean that you are creating a new PHP page for each user? If so a) how, and b) why? Normally this would be a single PHP page with the id of the user passed on the query string (e.g. `/dj.php?djid=42`)

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a new php page for each user because of SEO. So that if people search on google, the user can come out. Just like twitter, everyone has a page. I just felt it was possible to replace a word in the php section of the template, so that the user information can be pulled out whenever the page is visited.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach to the template is not good.

You have to separate the procesing from the rendering. If you don't want to use a template engine like smarty http://www.smarty.net/

You can have your template in a plain file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>{username} Home page</title> 
</head>

<body> 
Hello,<br /> 
<img href="{avatar}"/><br/>
this is my new home page. Here is my data:<br /><br />
Dj name: {djname}
<br /> 
Contact for booking: {email} <br /> 

</body>
</html>
```

And then your php code like

```
<?php
$id = //get the value from database, or post or get
$dj = Helper::getUserProfileInfo('dj',$id);
$template = file_get_contents('path/to/template');
$tags = array('{avatar}','{djname}','{email}');
$vals = array($dj->getAvatar(),$dj->getName(),$dj->getEmail());

echo str_replace($tags,$vals,$template);
```